# Can non-emptiness of a set be defined using only $\forall$ and $\exists!$ as quantifiers?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

Is there some integer $n$ and some quantifier-free formula $\phi$ of set theory in $2n+1$ variables $x,a_1,b_1,a_2,b_2,\ldots, a_n,b_n$ such that for any $x$, $x$ is nonempty iff $\forall a_1 \exists! b_1 \forall a_2 \exists! b_2 \ldots \forall a_n \exists! b_n \phi(x,a_1,b_1,\ldots, a_n,b_n)$ ?

(so $\phi$ can contain $\in,=$, negations and logical connectives but not quantifiers. And $\phi$ cannot contain the $\emptyset$ constant, of course. More formally, $\phi$ must be a Boolean function in the $2(n+1)(2n+1)$ variables $t_i\in t_j,t_i=t_j$, where the $t_i(1\leq i \leq 2n+1)$ are the variables $x,a_1,b_1,\ldots ,a_n,b_n$).

This question appears naturally in the context of another [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2488806/logic-and-set-theory-using-only-uniquely-defined-items/2489198?noredirect=1#comment5142838_2489198) I recently asked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$\exists!b \forall a (a\not\in b \land b\neq x)$$

The subformula $\forall a (a\not\in b \land b\neq x)$ can only possibly be satisfied by $b=\emptyset.$ And it is only true for $b=\emptyset$ when $x$ is non-empty.